# DateTimePicker is not working with angular material

Tags: angular-material

I wanted to implement a **DateTimePicker** using Angular Material. 
I came to this [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-datetimepicker) I went through all the steps. 
In the site there were some [live examples](https://beenote.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/) too. I was interested to implement the **DateRange Example**.

I found out that Angular Material doesn't use the `md-input-container` anymore, instead it uses `mat-form-field`. 
I copied the code and a strange DateTimePicker is showing, not like in the site.

I think maybe angular doesn't understand this `mdc-datetime-picker` or it could be because I used `mat-form-field`.

Here is the code which I implemented just for testing:

```
<div layout="column">
  <mat-form-field>
    <label>Start Date/Time</label>
    <input mdc-datetime-picker="" date="true" time="true" type="text"
           placeholder="Date" max-date="dateTimeEnd" ng-model="dateTimeStart" class=" md-input"
           readonly="readonly" id="input_0">
    <div></div>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Any Idea on where the problem could be?

Comment: There is a big difference between AngularJS and Angular, and the versions of Angular Material that are designed for each. The examples you are using are for AngularJS, but your code example is for Angular. `md-input-container` is from AngularJS Material for AngularJS, `mat-form-field` is from Angular Material for Angular. `mdc-datetime-picker` needs AngularJS / AngularJS Material, https://angularjs.org/, https://material.angularjs.org/latest/.

Comment: @G.Tranter aha thank you, I didn't know that I can't use this of AngularJS. Do you know if Angular offers a DateTimePicker like AngularJS?

Comment: Yes there's a standard material design datepicker in Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview. There are probably 3rd party ones available as well. Note that picker design is covered by Material Design guidelines https://material.io/design/components/pickers.html#desktop-pickers which is what Angular Material implements. If you want a different behaviour/look, you are 'breaking' material design 'rules'.

Comment: @G.Tranter I saw that material offers a datepicker, what I need is one with the time too. In the material docu I couldn't find anything for the time and date at once

Comment: You can use `<input matInput type="datetime-local">` but it doesn't look anywhere near as nice as the datepicker. There may be 3rd party components available.

Comment: @G.Tranter thank you, I chose the OwlDateTime from https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/ it looks good too :)